# Сохранить данные с сервера в Local Storage

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Запускаю процесс:

```
 function vhod() {
     $.get( "http://blabla.com/vhod.php", {..........} )
      .done(function( data ) {
          localStorage.setItem(data, value)
      });
 }
```

На сервере (`vhod.php`):

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT k_ls, v_ls FROM users");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo ($row['k_ls']);
 }
```

В итоге получаю значение только столбца `k_ls`, а хотелось бы все значения получить - и `k_ls` и `v_ls` для успешного сохранения. В таблице Mysql значений столбцов `k_ls` и `v_ls` может быть несколько.

Comment: вы что либо слышали про `json`? в каком виде вы вообще собираетесь сохранить эти значения, у вас сейчас там приходить должна одна строка объединяющая значения `k_ls`  всех строк выборки без каких либо разделителей. Как вы это планируете использовать?

Comment: Слышал, для моего случая не знаю как применить...

Comment: дак вы что с полученными данными хотите делать то по итогу? сейчас это у вас одна строка из `k_ls`.

Comment: localStorage.setItem(data, value) - вот что хочу. Понимаю что одна строка, как сделать чтобы не одна была?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не знаю, это ли вам надо,  но можно попробовать сделать так:
со стороны сервера сформируйте необходимые данные в формате JSON, отправив при этом соответствующие заголовки *(заметьте fetch-функция другая)*:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT k_ls, v_ls FROM users");

$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  //сохранит имена полей
    $data[] = $row;                          // добавить к результату
}

header("Content-type:application/json");     //отправить заголовок о типе контента  
echo json_encode($data);                     // и сами данные
```

на стороне клиента получив данные можете их записать в строку и в `localStorage`

```
$.get( "http://blabla.com/vhod.php", { ... } )
 .done(function( data ) {
      // получили JSON данные
      localStorage.setItem('myKey', JSON.stringify(data));
  });
```

далее когда понадобится, загрузите данные из localStorage

```
var strData = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
var data = JSON.parse(strData);
```

и обработаете их

```
$.each(data, function(idx, v) {
     console.log( idx +': ' +  v.k_ls + '/' + v.v_ls);
});
```

Comment: А как можно строчку: localStorage.setItem('myKey', JSON.stringify(data)); заменить на localStorage.setItem(значение k_ls, значение v_ls);?

Comment: Сейчас, после JSON.stringify(data)  имею: [{"k_ls":"22","v_ls":"11"},{"k_ls":"33","v_ls":"44"}], Но мне нужно сохранить так: localStorage.setItem('22', '11'); localStorage.setItem('33', '44');

Comment: как по мне, лучше тогда вариант `{ "22": 11, "33": 44}` хранить, они так хоть локализованы от других возможных данных. это будет правильнее. Для этого `$data[] = $row` замените на `$data[$row['k_ls']] = $row['v_ls']`;

Comment: но если надо как вы написали, то в `.done` должно быть `$.each(data, function(idx, v){ localStorage.setItem(v.k_ls, v.v_ls); }`